# Can we run more than one Parallel job at a time in DataStage?

Tags: parallel-processing, datastage

I was wondering if I can run more than one parallel job at a time in parallel.

I have two separate parallel jobs "Job1" and "Job2". 
What I can do is to put them in a sequence and then run. But this way once the Job1 is finished then Job2 starts.
Can I start them at the same time? Purpose is to optimize the jobs by saving time.

If I put them both in a sequence independently, without a link. Its doesn't work.
I tried to research but there is nothing specific out there on forums.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, we schedule a number of parallel (and some server jobs) jobs to run at given schedules. A lot of those schedules do overlap. These parallel jobs can run at the same time

http://ds.iexpertify.com/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Is there any other way to run more than one job at a time without the scheduler? If there isn't, then can we make a bunch of jobs to run at a given time daily with the help of some script or something? I have around 100 jobs, but they all can't run at the same time because a few of them are dependent on execution sequence. So is there a way to make a package of all the jobs that can run independently and then set that package to run all those jobs at a specific time daily.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you tried running the jobs in a sequence independently in a correct manner. Normally, that should work.

Comment: Hi Sriram, yes you are right. I was compromising the parallel logic later. But now, after correcting that. It worked like a charm in simple sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run both jobs parallely, but for this you have to use Sequencer, and running independent sequence is also possible, what was the issue showing when you are tring to run independent sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But you're going to have to uses a sequence job

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Without a sequence job and without a scheduler, simply use dsjob to request the run of each job.  DO NOT use -wait or -jobstatus option, and the dsjob command will be asynchronous.

You will need to create other processing if you need it to detect whether each job has finished.